# Weblogic LDAP connection timeout with CPU spikes

Tags: ldap, weblogic, cpu-usage, rhel, connection-timeout

We are observing high cpu utilization (sudden spikes to 100 percent) which is resulting in system becoming non-responsive, on analysis observed high no. of ldap connection time-out.
There is a service which is being used for authentication but, on running a trace it was observed that requests are not reaching Access management system and ldap time-out is occurring.

Please do share inputs on what could be reason(s) for ldaptime-out.

Want to add, no change been done to the system in recent past and this started occurring all of sudden and its weblogic on rhel. All required patches have been deployed to both OS, Application server.

Comment: Have you identified the classes that generate high cpu?

Comment: Observed JNDI initialization method not returning in weblogic form logs. Checked the cpu usgage, observed Its java process which is taking high cpu, and doing jstack noticed multiple jndi.ldap.Connection entries

Comment: Noticed thread count is very high, any suggestions on optimum execute thread count

Comment: with VisualVM you can check "live threads", under "Monitor"; and check details of any thread under the "Threads" tab. Please check, if there is any LDAP thread that could be causing high cpu usage.

Comment: No specific thread is causing it, what noticed thread count is high. Is there a way to thread pool size and accordingly set request wait time i.e. time-limit for request to wait before thread becomes available

Comment: Thread management is done through "Work Managers" https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/self_tuned.htm

Answer (score 0):

After multiple analysis, checking the stacks, solution which was arrived was to upsize VM
VM to handle higher volume of requests and not limit thread pool